# Google Chrome overflow vulnerability on resize() function

Tags: c++, google-chrome, security, vector, uint64

I am writing a paper for my undergraduate degree on vulnerabilities in google chrome, on a recent Chrome bug blog this was reported:

```
bool SampleAuxiliaryInformationOffset::Parse(BoxReader* reader) 
{
      RCHECK(reader->ReadFullBoxHeader());
      if (reader->flags() & 1)
        RCHECK(reader->SkipBytes(8));

      uint32_t count;
      RCHECK(reader->Read4(&count) &&
             reader->HasBytes(count * (reader->version() == 1 ? 8 : 4)));
      offsets.resize(count);

      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) 
      {
        if (reader->version() == 1) 
        {
          RCHECK(reader->Read8(&offsets[i]));
        } 
        else 
        {
          RCHECK(reader->Read4Into8(&offsets[i]));
        }
      }
      return true;
}
```

more info here
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=679641

with the following description of how the overflow occurred:

"count is read from mp4 file, which is between 0x0 and 0xffffffff. when reader->version() == 1, count * 8 will integer overflow, which bypass reader->HasBytes RCHECK.
What's more, offsets is defined as std::vector offsets;, offsets.resize(count) will malloc count * sizeof(uint64_t) bytes, this will also overflow, leading to out-of-bounds write."

My question is regarding the offsets.resize(count) overflow, i am not quite sure why it does overflow, i know count can be up to (2^32) so 4 bytes and sizeof(uint64_t)is 8 bytes meaning 32 bytes allocated with malloc. why does this overflow?